# How to get multiple data from firebase just with unique keys in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble retrieving data from firebase specific place. I have a state ("favourites" that was taken from firebase). Favourites state objects contain only unique firebase keys that were pushed when clicking "post add to favourites" (I have post data in firebase). So, how could i retrieve multiple post data with that unique keys which are in "favourites" node?

code:

```
class MyFavouriteScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      favourites: [],
      favouritesPosts: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    favouritesFire = firebase.database().ref('users').child(user + '/favourites');

    let that = this;
    favouritesFire.once("value", function(snapshot){
      let favs = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function(data){
        let fav = {
            id: data.key
        }
        favs.push(fav);
        that.setState({favourites: favs});
      });
    });
    // ^- there i get those unique keys and now i need to retrieve post data with those keys and show them in render function
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <MyNavScreen banner="Favoritai" navigation={ navigate } />
        <ScrollView style={styles.wrapper}>
      {this.state.favouritesPosts.map(post => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity post={post} style={styles.postWrapper}>
            <View style={styles.postImageWrapper}>
              <Image
                source={{uri: post.image}}
                style={{flex: 1}} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.shopContent}>
              <Text style={styles.postTitle}>{post.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.postText}>{post.text}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.starWrapper}>
              <Text style={styles.star}>{'-'}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your code and data structure?

Comment: Hey Ben thanx for reply. added my code

Comment: @Ben Can u help?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is not so good to deal with queries. I'd suggest you something like this

```
favouritesFire.once("value", snapshot => {
  snapshot.map(item => { // it will pass through all your snapshot items
    firebase.database().ref(`yournode/${item.key}`) //for each item you must query again in firebase
    .once('value')
    .then(itemFiltered => console.log('Your item: ', itemFiltered); // then you get your result
  })
})
```

Hope it helps